# Ошибка outofmemory при декомпрессии ab (Android Backup) файла

Tags: c#

На англоязычной версии сайта нашел метод, который мне очень подходит:

```
 public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
        {
            using (var stream = new Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                const int size = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                    while (count > 0);
                    return memory.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Для вызова метода пользуюсь

```
private void converttotarTool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        byte[] app = Decompress(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\ab\2017-01-03_141454.ab"));
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\ab\backup.tar", app);
    }
```

Если конвертировать в ".tar" бекапы небольшого размера, то проблем не возникает. В моем случае бекап 1,6 гб - возникает ошибка outofmemory.
Подскажите, как исправить метод чтобы все содержимое закидывалось в оперативную память частями?

Answer (score 2):

Навряд ли поможет, но стоит попробовать сразу в файл записывать сжатые куски.

ZlibStream можно инициализировать любым стримом, так что не обязательно весь файл в памяти держать, а только куски по 1024, как у Вас и было, и записывать сжатый результат сразу в выходной файл:

```
    public static void Decompress(string input, string output)
    {
        using (var stream = new Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream(File.OpenRead(input), Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            const int size = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (FileStream file = File.Create(output))
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);

                    if (count > 0)
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                } while (count > 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к правильному ответу @Umed: вы не должны проводить ваши операции в памяти. У вас информация содержится в нескольких местах: она читается из файла в массив вся, потом из массива делается `MemoryStream`, который содержит копию информации, потом другой `MemoryStream` содержит декомпрессированную информацию, потом массив содержит копию декомпрессированной информации, и это всё сбрасывается в файл. Для «поточных» операций по кускам имеет смысл, как правильно написано в другом ответе, использовать именно потоки.

Результирующий код может быть таким (упростил пример @Umed):

```
public static void Decompress(string input, string output)
{
    using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(input))
    using (var zlibStream = new Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream(inputStream,
                                                      Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(output))
        zlibStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
}
```

Comment: возникает ошибка "Bad state (unknown compression method (0x41))" на строке "zlibStream.CopyTo(outputStream);". Не знаете в чем проблема ?

Comment: @Yuri: А так со всеми файлами, или только с одним?

Comment: Попробовал на нескольких - с ними возникает. При том, что с помощью java android backup extractor все расжимается нормально.

Comment: @Yuri: А с вашим кодом из вопроса распаковывается? Это важно.

Comment: С кодом из вопроса не хватает памяти

Comment: @Yuri: А на маленьких файлах с кодом из вопроса распаковывается?

Comment: Нет возможности посмотреть, так как бекапы больше 600 мб =(

Comment: @Yuri: Чёрт побери, это хуже, непонятно, где проблема. А есть возможность создать маааааленький бекап искусственно?

Comment: @Yuri: Вот вы ж пишете «Если конвертировать в ".tar" бекапы небольшого размера, то проблем не возникает» — то есть где-то можно раздобыть маленький бекап?

Comment: @Yuri, можно просто сжать любой другой файл, не обязательно бекап и проверить

Comment: Попробовал на маленьком файле, пишет Bad state (unknown compression method (0x41))

Comment: Извините за флуд, но похоже, что данный метод не работает. Буду подключать android backup extractor, написанный на java, и дальше разбираться как расжать данный бекап средствами c#.

Comment: @Yuri: А что не работает? Ваш метод из вопроса тоже? Выложите куда-нибудь файл, попробую поэкспериментировать.